# Some some code crashes my application on flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cross-platform

Im new in flutter, so i follow someone's tutorial to make music player app, everything normal until my app suddenly crashed, i tried to re-run the app but still it's crashed and i try to remove the code that last time i create and the app run normal, so what's wrong with the code?, sorry for my bad english.

```
 ....////
Widget _buildWidgetArtistName(MediaQueryData mediaQuery) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: mediaQuery.size.height / 1.8,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  child: Text(
                    'Grande',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'CoralPen',
                      fontSize: 72.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  top: constraints.maxHeight - 100.0,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Text(
                    'Ariana',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'CoralPen',
                      fontSize: 72.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  top: constraints.maxHeight - 140.0,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: Text(
                    'Tranding',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF7D9AFF),
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Campton_Light',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    ),
                  ),
                  top: constraints.maxHeight - 160.0,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldState,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          _buildWidgetAlbumCover(mediaQuery),
          _buildWidgetActionAppBar(mediaQuery),
          _buildWidgetArtistName(mediaQuery), // This causing crash
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the error? The code for the function _buildWidgetArtistName does not seem to cause any errors.

Comment: Try to run flutter clean command,if your code is right